# Using a .bat file how do I copy a file from its current directory to another directory?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I want to be able to have the batch file in any directory and have it copy the file to the specified directory. I have tried using:

```
set path="%~dp0"
copy "%path%\test.txt" "C:\"
```

```
pushd "%~dp0"
copy "%~dp0\test.txt" "C:\"
```

```
copy "\test.txt" "C:\"
```

but the only one that worked was when I typed out the entire directory for the file

```
copy "C:\WORK\PRogramering1\test.txt" "C:\"
```

Every time I ran the code I ran it in admin so that is not the problem. I have tried using solutions I have found by googling but they did not help.

Comment: From your description I get the feeling that this `.bat` file is enough: `copy "test.txt" "C:\"`. This is too simple, so please give more details. Note: The `C:\` root directory should be avoided as a workplace and reserved for Windows.

Comment: Can you describe the way in which it did not work? Did the `copy` command output an error message?

Comment: The problem was that i was trying to copy it to a folder that required admin, even though I ran it in admin. copying worked like harrymc said when I copied it to another folder. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

##### harrymc's comment

> From your description I get the feeling that this .bat file is enough: `copy "test.txt" "C:\"`. This is too simple, so please give more details. Note: The `C:` root directory should be avoided as a workplace and reserved for Windows

The problem was that I was trying to copy the file to a directory that required admin, so when I changed directory the code harrymc told me to use worked

Comment: Please dont use images for text information.  People can not copy paste from it.  I have replaced it for you.  There is no shame in quoting someone, as long as you give them credit.

Comment: I understand, will keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
@echo off 

::-------------------------------------------------::

                 copy /y "%~dp0test.txt" "C:\" 

pause 
::-------------------------------------------------::

pushd "%~dp0" 
                 copy /y .\"test.txt" "C:\"
                 copy "test.txt" "C:\"
popd
pause
::-------------------------------------------------::

pushd "C:\"
                 copy /y "%~dp0test.txt" .
                 copy /y "%_path%\test.txt" .
popd
pause 
::-------------------------------------------------::

set "_path=%~dp0"
                 copy /y "%_path%test.txt" "C:\"
                 copy /y "%_path%\test.txt" "C:\"
pause 
::-------------------------------------------------::

setlocal
set "_path_file=%~dp0test.txt"
                 copy /y "%_path_file%" "C:\" 
endlocal
::-------------------------------------------------::
```

---

**1** Know the **[`%Path%`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)** variable, it is a system variable, so avoid using it (and the others too), this really causes unexpected behavior.

---

**2.** Listen to **[ss64.com's](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)** advice/tip for the **`set`** command:

***[`The first character of the name must not be numeric. It is a common practice to prefix variable names with either an undescore or a dollar sign _variable or $variable, these prefixes are not required but help to prevent any confusion with the standard built-in Windows Environment variables or any other other command strings.`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)***

---

## Additional Resources:

**[Standard (built-in) Variables](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)**

- [`Cd /?`  | `ChDir /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)
- [`Pushd /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)  and [`Popd /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html)
- [`Setlocal /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) and [`Endlocal /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html)
- [`Copy /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html)